# Convert string date (Month, Year) to time.Time

Tags: go

I have a string which is :

```
str := "Jan 2020"
```

I need to convert this to time.time format in go.How can i do this please ?

Comment: i get thi errro parsing time "Jan 2020" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "Jan 2020" as "2006"
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a layout string that specifies how to parse your string. For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    time, err := time.Parse("Jan 2006", "Feb 2020")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(time)
}
```

You may find more about the standard layouts [here](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go).